# Unable to connect the Oracle server on 64 bit machine through ASP.NET on 64 bit machine

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I am new to Oracle..and i am working on a ASP.NET Application whose backend is Oracle 11g.

I have 2 Machines for development. One is the Database Server(Windows Server 2008 R2) and second is the Application server(Windows 7).
I have installed a Oracle server 11g standard edition on Database server machine.
I have installed the Visual Studio 2010 and oracle 11g client on the Application server.

Now i am able to connect the oracle database server through the Application server using Toad.

But when i try to connect the database server through the ASP.NET 4.0 Application, then i am unable to connect the oracle and get the following error...

> Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.
>   This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit
>   Oracle client components installed.

I have tried to set the Target Platform to x64 , but still it didnt work...

Any Help/Suggestions will be appreciated....

Thanks in Advance.....

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be exactly what it says. Looks like the Oracle Client you have installed is a 32-bit Oracle client. Download and install the 64-bit version of Oracle client.

Comment: Hi Ranhiru, 
Thanks for you reply...
But we have 64-bit version of Oracle client installed. And this thing has been checked by the DB guys...

Any other suggestions/Solutions/Patches...?

Comment: Take a look at this link. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/132649/Attempt-to-load-Oracle-client-libraries-threw-BadI